# Добавление метода в автозагрузку asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Здравствуйте.

Имеется приложение на asp.net, mvc.
Нужно каждые 30 минут совершать определенное действие.
Как можно добавить определенный метод в автозагрузку сайта?

Comment: Поместите таймер либо на стороне клиента в JS-коде либо на стороне сервера. Если не требуется обращение к БД либо к модели, то лучше завести таймер в JS.